# How to change the select option background color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

**How should I change the select option background color. I'm using bootstrap 4.**
``

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <select class="form-control >
       <option  value="mechanical">Mechanical</option>
       <option  value="cs">Computer Science</option>
       <option  value="civil">Civil</option>
       <option  value="agricultural">Agricultural</option>
   </select>
```

``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the background via CSS.

```css
select {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group ">
        <select class="form-control >
           <option  value="mechanical">Mechanical</option>
           <option  value="cs">Computer Science</option>
           <option  value="civil">Civil</option>
           <option  value="agricultural">Agricultural</option>
       </select>
    </div>
```